# Is there a way to override ansible ssh user from inventory for a play?

Tags: ansible

If my ansible_user and ansible_ssh_pass is defined in an inventory, could I override that ansible_user when running a specific play?

I want to be able to keep one inventory but there is a specific play that I want to access as a different ssh user.

Answer (score 3):

You can override `ansible_ssh_user` at the **play** level by passing in a `vars:` section to the relevant play.

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_ssh_user

- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_user: my_user_123
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_ssh_user
```

This playbook has 2 plays. In the second play, I am overriding the ansible_ssh_user variable.